# R attach multiple datasets in one - is rbind the best?

Tags: append, rbind

I have 7 different datasets that all contain the exact same columns (same names and same type of data) and I want to add them all together into one big dataset - they are all files from the same database but were originally extracted in 7 different smaller files due to size.

So I have:

```
  df1
  var1  var2    var3
   NY   300      abc
   LA   500      def
```

And

```
  df2
  var1  var2    var3
   MI   200      ght
   OR   900      pth
```

And so on with df3 to df7. I'd like to attach them one after the other to get:

```
  Big.Dataset 
  var1  var2    var3
   NY   300      abc
   LA   500      def
   MI   200      ght
   OR   900      pth
```

I tried the following:

```
   Big.Dataset <- rbind(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7)
```

But when I then do

```
   View(Big.Dataset)
```

All I can see is 1 row and 1 column. So clearly, the function didn't work.

What is it exactly that I'm doing wrong? Is rbind the right function? Is it something wrong with my files that I need to fix before doing rbind perhaps?

Comment: What are the types of `df1`, `df2`, etc.?  Can you show us exact code so that we may reproduce this error?

Comment: df1, df2, etc. are .csv files. I am trying to see whether it was an issue of how I imported the files. It seems I have now managed to import the files  in R and when I run rbind to create Big.Dataset  I can see on the right panel of R-studio the file having 197,000 obs and 27 variables. But still when I do View(Big.Dataset) I keep seeing only 1 row and 1 column...

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The issue was that I had to define the variables first - as.numeric or as.character. That way R could recognise what it had to do.